# Help needed in refining PHP search

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to create a php search engine which can refine search results based on time similar to google's search refine but with a select dropdown without a submit button.

I am using sql server as database with pdo-sqlsrv driver. The regular search works great. I have problem only in passing value in time variable through select box and loading the page as soon as user selects the option.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<select name="foo" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();">`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript , you can do something like... 
onchange="mysubmit()"